# How do I set up custom code completion for Ext UX components in Spket?

Tags: extjs, aptana, spket

I've recently got Aptana Studio 3 set up with Spket to provide syntax highlighting and (more importantly) code completion for Ext JS.

This seems to work fine for the standard Ext components. Is it possible to get code completion for custom `ext.ux` components too? I've tried adding the .js files to the javascript profile (like I added the `ext.jsb` for the core Ext) but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get auto suggestion for `Ext.ux components`,

Edit the ext.jsb2 file and locate the `User Extension JS Pack`
under that add the Ext.ux componet js file path in fileIncludes array.
like

```
 {
   "name"    : "User Extension JS Pack",
   "file"    : "examples/ux/ux-all.js",
   "isDebug" : true,
   "fileIncludes" : [{
      "text" : "SuperBoxSelect.js",
      "path" : "examples/ux/"
      }]
 }
```

save the file and restart your editor.
check for the added component auto suggest.